# Запрос не обновляет данные в БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Нужно в БД обновить строку, на прямую sql запрос работает, а на сайте нет.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('bd.php');

    $taskid = 181;
    $taskname = "aaa";
    $tasktext = "bbb";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `oc_product_description` SET name='$taskname', description='$tasktext' WHERE product_id=$taskid");
?>
```

Comment: Он работает. Просто Вы забываете получить результат выполнения запроса. А зря - его можно было бы посмотреть и понять, что серверу не нравится...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `oc_product_description` SET name='$taskname', description='$tasktext' WHERE product_id=$taskid");
```

пишите

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `oc_product_description` SET name='$taskname', description='$tasktext' WHERE product_id=$taskid")
          or exit(mysqli_error($con));
```

чтобы вам на экран текст ошибки выводился при ее возникновении.